# Kohana 3: Callback validation

Tags: validation, callback, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.0

> **NOTE:** This question refers to **Kohana 3.0** only.  Kohana 3.1 and newer handle validation callbacks in a completely different way.

I'm doing a validation with a callback (ORM). These are my code:

```
class Model_Loja extends ORM {
    // more code goes here!
    protected $_callbacks = array(
        'endereco' => array('endereco_unico')
    );

    public function endereco_unico(Validate $validate, $campo) {
        $resultado = $this->where('endereco', '=', $this->endereco)->find_all();
        if(count($resultado)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // more code goes here!
```

It's returning true or false (if there is a value, returns false) but how could i send a validation message when it returns false?

Answer (score 0):

The following validation function sets an error for the field if validation fails:

```
public function endereco_unico(Validate $validate, $campo) {
    if(count($this->where('endereco', '=', $this->endereco)->find_all())) {
        $validate->error($campo, 'endereco_unico');
    }
}
```

(Moved from question)